# Data coming from Redis cache is not paginated

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, caching, redis

Before I implemented Redis cache in my backend api, pagination was working fine on the backend and on the frontend, after caching the data, it does not work any longer.
Here is my middleware that runs before I get all data

```
const checkCache = (req, res, next) => {
  client.get("posts", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      sendFailureResponse(res, 500, err);
    }
    if (data != null) {
      sendSuccessResponse(res, 200, JSON.parse(data));
    } else {
      //proceed to next middleware function
      next();
    }
  });
};
```

The controller

```
const page = parseInt(req.query.page);
    const size = parseInt(req.query.size);
    const query = {};
    if (page < 0 || page === 0) {
      sendFailureResponse(res, 400, "invalid page number")
    }
    query.skip = size * (page - 1);
    query.limit = size;

    const posts = await Post.find({}, {}, query).populate("user", ["name"]);
    client.setex("posts", 3600, JSON.stringify(posts))
    sendSuccessResponse(res, 200, posts);
  } catch (err) {
    sendFailureResponse(res, 500, err.message);
  }
```

How can I return the paginated result from the cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add the page number to the key (`'page' + req.query.page`), and then you'll have cache per page

BTW, you have a bug in the `checkCache` middleware:
if there is an error, you call both `sendFailureResponse` and `next` functions, and you'll get "ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END" error

Comment: Thanks, @Leibale. Do you mean adding an extra key to this?
client.setex("posts", 3600, JSON.stringify(posts))

Comment: @Fehmy you can think on a redis server as an object, and every time you call `client.setex(key, ttl, value)` it'll set/*override* the value for the "key" with the value you sent. in you're case, every time you call `client.setex('posts', ...)` you set the value of `posts` to be the current page, but then if someone makes an API call for a different page you search in the `posts` key without making sure the page that was cached is the page you want to return. If you want to have cache per page, adding the page number into the key (as I've described in the answer) will "solve" the issue